# read out serial device and save data working with double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have some problems with reading out some data of a serial device, storing them and printing them on the console. The printing has sometimes errors.
I allocate memory in my main function with malloc that way:

```
 char * outputBuf = (char*)malloc(*1024sizeof(char));
```

I call my read function with:

```
 readSerialData(atCommandHandler, &outputBuf);
```

My readSerialData-Function:

```
 int atCommandRead(int *atCommandHandler, char **outputBuf)
 {
   size_t total=0;
   int retval;

   FD_ZERO(&portsetmaster);
   FD_SET((int)atCommandHandler, &portsetmaster);
   int fullframe=0;
   memcpy(&portsetlisten, &portsetmaster, sizeof(portsetmaster));
   if(select(atCommandHandler+1, &portsetlisten, NULL, NULL,NULL)>0)         ///< tbd: select also on error
   {
       retval = read(atCommandHandler, *outputBuf, AT_BUFFER_MAX);
       *(outputBuf+retval) = '\0';                                               // terminate array outputBuf with \0
   }
   printf("Buffer: %s\n", *outputBuf);
   return retval;
}
```

Sometimes my Output looks like that:
OKVISION 01.010
OKVISION 01.010

Actually it should look like that:
Florian
ABCD
REVISION 01.010
Can anyone sees some mistakes in the code?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: `*(outputBuf+retval) = '\0';` -->> `(*outputBuf)[retval] = '\0';`

Comment: Also, you must first make sure that `retval != -1` ; which could have terrible effects.

Comment: by  `char * outputBuf = (char*)malloc(*1024sizeof(char));` you mean  `char * outputBuf = malloc(1024);`  right?

Comment: Maybe `select()` returned -1 to indicate an error?